# Consultar entre un rango de fechas de un json en mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

Tengo la siguiente colección en mongodb, quiero obtener la `cveUsuario`,`activo` y el `historial`, pero el historial solo los días que esté en el rango de fechas seleccionado por el usuario.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5847167aa7f950253039ef7e"),
  "cveUsuario": "000210",
  "activo": true,
  "historial": {
    "13 Jan 2017": {
      "VFVNTF03": [
        "09:38:33",
        "09:38:57",
        "09:39:38",
        "09:40:37"
      ],
      "CHPAGF099": [
        "16:38:41",
        "16:41:16"
      ]
    },
    "14 Jan 2017": {
      "CHRCAF003": [
        "09:33:21",
        "09:33:43"
      ],
      "CHPAGF099": [
        "10:36:22",
        "12:13:14"
      ]
    }
  },...
  {...}
}
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta pero cuando la uso en JAVA esta no me trae resultados, dado que si el usuario ingresa más de 4 días esta se hace más grande.

```
db.getCollection('sesiones').find({
    historial:{$exists:true},
    $or:[
        {"historial.24 Nov 2018":{$exists:true}},
        {"historial.23 Nov 2018":{$exists:true}},
        {"historial.22 Nov 2018":{$exists:true}}
    ]
},{
    cveUsuario:1,
    activo:1,
    "historial.24 Nov 2018":1,
    "historial.23 Nov 2018":1,
    "historial.22 Nov 2018":1
})
```

Hay alguna forma de simplificar la consulta que tengo, soy reciente en las consultas con mongodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer un $where, y generar la busqueda que deseas

```
db.sesiones.find({ 
    $where: function() { 
                dia = 24
                function exists(obj){
                    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`historial`)){
                          if (obj.historial.hasOwnProperty(`${dia +  i}Jan 2017`)){
                                    return true;
                                } 
                        }
                        return false;    

                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return  exists(this)
        } 
    })
```

Comment: no me devuelve ningún registro

Comment: el error es como recorro las propiedades puedes intentar obj.historial.hasOwnProperty(`${dia +  i}Jan 2017`)

Comment: me devuelve el siguiente error `Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "TypeError: obj.historial is undefined :\nexists@:5:1\n_funcs2@:11:25\n",
 "code" : 139
}`

Comment: Me trae resultados solo si la fecha es superior a 10 los anteriores por no estar en `01 ... 09` no los obtiene. Eso sería ya verlo con los compañeros para ver si se hace el cambio a 1 solo dígito los primeros días.

Comment: Si, funcionó, solo los días anteriores de 10 son los que habría que ver si se hace el cambio

Comment: Le puedes dar formato al número