# Buscar tablas con determinado campo pero en Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hola estoy trabajando con `Mongodb` y no tengo demasiados conocimientos, quiero hacer lo que dice el titulo, buscar las tablas que tengan cierto campo, que para esta caso no sql, creo seria buscar documentos con cierta key, tengo el siguiente codigo en `Mysql` que es el que quiero adaptar a mongo.

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Door%'
```

Lo cual me genera las `tablas` que contengan `Door`.
Para `MongoDB` estuve usando `find()` de la siguiente manera

```
db.startup_log.find({"Door":1})
```

El problema es que tiene que ser exactamente el campo `Door` con valor `1`, pero realmente no se si el campo se llame asi o tenga ese valor, porque podría ser `N_Door`, `No_Door`, etc.

Eso en `mysql` si me lo arroja como quisiera, pero en `MongoDB` aun no encuentro la forma, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: para buscar si existe un campo es el comando [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) `db.startup_log.find( { Door: { $exists: true } } )`

Comment: respondi algo parecido, [mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217500/28035)

Comment: Gracias, soluciono lo del `valor`, pero aun no se como hacer lo de la `clave` que como menciono, tiene que ser exactamente `Door` pero podria tener otro nombre, lo que quisiera es buscar aunque no coincidan, si no que contengan `Door` ej. `NDoor`, `Door1` etc.
Gracias por tu comentario, me ayudo

Comment: fijate la respuesta que te envie, es dinamica

Comment: Si, lo estoy probando para entenderle, gracias

Comment: el if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`historial`)){ alli va el door

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de lograr lo que te propones es usando una expresión regular para evaluar el nombre del campo en tu documento, de esta forma si un documento contiene un campo que coincida con la expresión regular, el mismo será devuelto por la consulta.

Recuerda que MongoDB es un sistema de Base de Datos [***schemaless***](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/why-schemaless), con esto quiero decir que no está pensado para realizar búsquedas sobre los nombres de campos, como lo haces normalmente con una base de datos tipo SQL.

Podrías entonces crear una función que devuelva los documentos que contengan al menos un campo que coincida con el patrón de una expresión regular que indiques.

La eficiencia de la búsqueda va a depender de lo compleja que sea la expresión regular. Además, he de mencionar que la búsqueda aquí planteada no es de ninguna manera óptima.

Un ejemplo muy básico de lo que pretendes lograr sería el siguiente:

```
db.startup_log.find({
    $where: function() {
        const regexp = new RegExp('Door','g');
        const match = (document) => {
            for(field in document) {
                if(regexp.test(field)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return match(this);
    }
});
```

La expresión regular que se usa en este ejemplo es `Door` (puedes encontrar más información sobre `RegExp` en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)), con esto se realiza un búsqueda global sobre el nombre de cada campo en cada documento de nuestra colección.

La función `match` devolverá `true` para el primer campo encontrado que contenga la cadena `Door`. Así, el operador [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) añadirá dicho documento al resultado de la búsqueda.

Si ningún campo del documento contiene la cadena `Door`, la función `match` devolverá `false`, por lo tanto el operador `$where` no añadirá dicho documento al resultado de la búsqueda.

Así tienes una forma (similar a tu consulta SQL) para encontrar documentos de una colección de Mongo, que tengan un campo cuyo nombre se parezca (contenga) a la cadena que te interesa (en este caso `Door`).

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscabas.

**EDICION**

Dado que en tus comentarios dices usar Mongo 3.2, el problema se presenta en que dicha versión implementa en su motor de Javascript el [soporte mejorado de ES6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-javascript/), por lo tanto las [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions), sin embargo puede haber algún tipo de incompatibilidad en la forma en la que se está realizando la asignación.

La solución es refactorizar para cumplir con los requerimientos de tu versión y usar el antiguo pero muy compatible ES5.

Una forma de lograrlo, es usando lo siguiente:

```
db.startup_log.find({
    $where: function() {
        const regexp = new RegExp('Door','g');
        const match = function(document) { // aquí no se usa la función flecha
            let fields = Object.keys(document); // usamos un array para almacenar el nombre de los campos
            for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) { // iteramos usando un for loop clásico
                if(regexp.test(fields[i])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return match(this);
    }
});
```

Otra forma de lograr lo mismo sería la siguiente: (colaboración de @JackNavaRow)

```
db.startup_log.find({
    $where: function() {
        const regexp = new RegExp('Door','g');
        const match = function(document) { // aquí no se usa la función flecha
            // creamos una cadena separada por comas con todos los nombres de los campos
            // esto evita realizar una iteración
            let fields = Object.keys(document).join(',');
            // si algún campo contiene Door, el test dará true
            if(regexp.test(fields)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return match(this);
    }
});
```

Espero que ahora sí puedas solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Me marca SyntaxError: Unexpected token > 
viendo la estructura no encuentro donde puede estar mal, gracias por tu respuesta, usar expresiones regulares si puede solucionar mi problema, saludos

Comment: Hice una corrección en el código. Tenía un error al copiar y pegar y me dejé por fuera el `return match(this);`. Saludos

Comment: Ahora me sale lo siguiente `Error: error: { "$err" : "SyntaxError: Unexpected token >", "code" : 16722 }`. Probablemente este haciendo algo mal, vere si puedo hacerlo correr, igual lo dejo por si con el error que me arroja lo visualizas rapidamente, gracias

Comment: @LuisAlejandro podrias agregar el codigo que ejecutastes a tu pregunta y agregar la version de mongodb

Comment: mongo 4.0 funciona

Comment: Es exactamente el mismo código y es mongo 3.2, no se si con eso aun quieras que lo agregue a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ese es el problema, ya te edito la respuesta @LuisAlejandro